# Reading Laravel Whoops Page, ReflectionException

Tags: laravel, whoops

I have a `ReflectionException (-1)` "Class does not exist error" in Laravel. I know it is a namespacing issue as I have been messing with the namespaces.

I'm just trying to read this incredible callstack on the Whoops! error page to find my file that caused the error.

There's 34 frames and all of them are internal Laravel files and not my file that caused the error.

Is there an simple way/a trick to reading this call stack, or maybe some other information on the Whoops! error page, so that one can quickly pinpoint the source (my own file) of a problem like this?

Comment: last time i had reflection exception, it was php version requirement unmet problem

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out, not sure why the file isn't listed.

But 1 "trick" would be to just search for any references to the class name that it says doesn't exist. And fix the namespaces wherever it is referenced.

Comment: Gee, thanks me. But that doesn't really answer the question, I was hoping Whoops!!! would tell me which file has the bad reference.

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja Yes should have done that. Because now can't reproduce ^^. Will add in if I can.